# Flutter go router pass List dynamic to parameter

Tags: string, flutter, list, flutter-web, router

i was using go router for flutter app i can pass String parameters between activities and its working now i want to pass list dynamic and am getting error

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'List'. (Documentation)

Receiver activity have

```
class EditUserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  final List<dynamic> userinformation;
 
}
```

on Route builder i have passed my data like below

```
GoRoute(
            path: 'editusers',
            name:
                'editusers/:name,:userinformation,'
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
return EditUserPage(
 state.params["name"]!,
 state.params["userinformation"]!,
)
);
```

The error comes on this line   **state.params["userinformation"]!,**  **The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***You can use this method***

> step 1

```
class ScreenArguments{
  final Key? key;
  final List<dynamic> list;
  final DateTime dateTime;
  ScreenArguments({
    this.key,
    required this.list,
    required this.dateTime,
  });
}
```

> step 2

```
builder: (context, state) {
            return Screen(
              arguments: state.extra as ScreenArguments,
            );
          },
```

> step 3

```
  final ScreenArguments arguments;
  const Screen({
    super.key,
    required this.arguments,
  });
```

> step 4

```
context.pushNamed(
           'name',
    extra: ScreenArguments(
      list:list,
          dateTime: dateTime,
                           ),
                           );
```